# Flutter form input search with dropdown - API Json

Tags: dart, flutter

I was wondering if someone had an good example of a form field input where you can search through a list of items in a dropdown, from a api in json format.

I have found some examples but not really good working anymore.

I hope somebody can help me out!

Greetings,
SJente